# Url parameters work on Chrome, Firefox but not on Safari

Tags: google-chrome, url, firefox, redirect, safari

I have a banner that redirects to a page with the url in the form of:

```
http://pn.example.com/go.cgi?pid=60&wmid=cc&cpid=1&prid=1&target=www.mydomain.com/valencia/hotels#?hotelName=Husa%20Dimar&ci=2014-08-22&co=2014-08-24&pid=60&utm_campaign=DE-%5BAF%5Bpn_01%7Cpub_60%5D%5D&utm_source=pn&utm_medium=affiliate
```

the above url works perfectly on Chrome and on Firefox but on Safari the parameters after the hashtag are not passed, so it goes to `www.mydomain.com/valencia/hotels` without the parameters. Any idea why this is happening, is the hash special character? How can it be fixed?

Comment: is this your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882857/hashtags-in-url-encoded-parameters-decoded-on-redirect

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by replacing the hash with %23