# 301 redirect of an url that contains a hashtag replaces the hashtag with %23 in the browser address bar.

Tags: hashtag

I tried a 301 redirect in `CPanel` but when the redirected url appears in the browser address bar it has the hashtag changed to %23.
With this change the final destination is never reached. Here is the URL:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ace%20hardware%20norcross%20ga&lrd=0x88f5a08e7fc35a07:0xe1ccba95a38c346b,1,,

Can anyone find a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882857/hashtags-in-url-encoded-parameters-decoded-on-redirect

Answer (score 0):

If you create a 301 redirect using cPanel, it uses default rewrite rule modifiers and the URL will be encoded.
Check your .htaccess file, find that 301 rewrite rule. It should look similar to this:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Add a modifier so it looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

The NE modifier will disable encoding.